# Recover de DUMP do Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Recebi um banco de dados do Oracle 11g para análise, mas o arquivo de dump está no formato *.datp* . Não encontrei em nenhum lugar da internet referência sobre esse tipo de arquivo. As instruções do cliente são "tem que usar o Oracle" mas:

1- tenho conhecimento superficial em Oracle

2- esse banco deverá ser migrado do Oracle para o MySQL

3- Tenho o Oracle XE 11g instalado mas nem ele tem alguma ferramenta que abra esse arquivo (pelo menos não aparentemente).

Alguma luz de como abrir e importar esse banco de dados para o Oracle ou MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Já tentou usar o comando [impdp](https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/oracle-data-pump-10g)?

Achei o seguinte exemplo:

```
impdp SPEND_DBA/SPEND_DBA@ SPEND102 directory=dump
dumpfile=SeuArquivoDump.dmp
logfile=SeuArquivoDeLog.log
```

Para ver a descrição completa do exemplo acima [acesse esse link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSYQ72_10.0.4/com.ibm.help.suiteinstall1004.reportconfig.doc/R_ImpotringDumpFileInOracleUser.html).

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado!

Comment: @user3021610 que bom que funcionou! Quando possível, marque como resposta que poderá ajudar mais pessoas. :)

Comment: Esqueci de fazê-lo, obrigado por lembrar!